# How to eliminate spaces in list containing numbers in python?

Tags: python-3.x, api, url, python-requests

I have a list, which is to be passed as part of params to URL.

```
params={"some_value":[1234, 5678]}
```

Observe the `space before 5678`
As a number wise, it doesn't make any difference.
But when passed as parameter, it looks like `http://some_url/abcd?some_value=[1234,%205678]`

```
%20 gets added to space.
```

Any way, how can i eliminate this kind of `space existing in list` ?

```
response = requests_session.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=params, json=None,verify=False, timeout=1000)
```

Should look like `params={"some_value":[1234,5678]}` and `http://some_url/abcd?some_value=[1234,5678]`

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is this. Before you pass it as a parameter,

```
params["some_value"] = str(params["some_value"]).replace(" ", "")
```

---

```
>>> params
{'some_value': '[1234,5678]'}
>>>
```

On the front-end side:

```
JSON.parse('[1234,5678]')
```

Returns

```
> (2) [1234, 5678]
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked.
I tried strip() and strip(' '), some_val = [1234, 5678] 
some_val = [int(str(i).strip(' ')) for i in some_val] . But this hasn't worked.

Comment: I see your line of thought there. However, the reason that the space existed is not due to the value in the array, but due to the array itself. Whenever you create an array,`', '` is between every item in the array. Thus, since the space was not a part of the value in the array, the `strip` would not do anything.

Comment: Right, got it. Can it be applied to list (as applied to dictionary above) ?

Comment: The list here is simply a field in the dictionary, so this will work with an individual list as well.

Comment: {'some_value': '[1234,5678]'} , value here is of type string. Can it be changed to original type, i.e., list ?

Comment: I see query failing, because of it's type. Can it be changed ?